# Wait functions without stop

Tags: c

How to get child (generated by fork()) info (using one of the wait function) without stoping the calling process ? (in c language)

```
    while((waitpid(p , &i , 0) > 0))
    {
        continue;
    }
```

please help

Answer (score 0):

The `waitpid()` function's third argument is a bitmask of options, one of which is (symbolically) `WNOHANG`.  If you include that among the options then `waitpid()` will not block, even if the specified child is still running.  You can then determine whether the child process has, in fact, terminated by testing the value returned via the second argument:

```
if (WIFEXITED(i)) {
    /* ... handle normal exit ... */
else if (WIFSIGNALED(i)) {
    /* ... handle exit because of a signal ... */
}
```

You cannot get the child's exit status or clean it up until it has in fact exited, however, so it is only useful for the parent to do this if it has other work to perform while the child runs.  In that case, it will need to periodically perform a `waitpid()` until it finds that the child has terminated, or else it needs some other way for the child to tell it when it's done (signal, I/O, IPC).